# Куда-то исчезает место, как найти виновника?

Tags: linux, vmware

Хост: гипервизор esxi, на нем 3 датастора (3 реид массива )
Каждые 20мин отжирает по 1м на одном из датасторов.
Конфигурация ВМ, диск толстый то есть место выделено сразу. Думал, что проблема в лог файле так как он пух оч быстро и я его решил удалить. В надежде, что место перестанет убывать. Но все равно ситуация продолжилась.

```
/vmfs/volumes/51808b6b-b7ae6443-e788-10bf484ee5cb # du -sh
```

Объем датастора: 470.9G

```
Filesystem        Bytes         Used   Available Use% Mounted on
VMFS-5     510832672768 506097303552  4735369216  99% /vmfs/volumes/dc
```

и через промежуток времени

```
Filesystem        Bytes         Used   Available Use% Mounted on
VMFS-5     510832672768 506098352128  4734320640  99% /vmfs/volumes/dc
```

через консоль

```
VMFS-5     475.8G 471.3G      4.4G  99% /vmfs/volumes/dc
```

через графическую оснастку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

виртуалка

```
/vmfs/volumes/51808b6b-b7ae6443-e788-10bf484ee5cb/dc # ls -lha
total 493002784
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.8K Apr  4 09:27 .
drwxr-xr-t    1 root     root        1.2K Dec 19  2014 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          27 Jul 17  2015 dc-06badfdf.hlog
-rw-------    1 root     root           0 Mar 29 18:03 dc-06badfdf.vswp
-rw-------    1 root     root      470.0G Apr  5 06:37 dc-flat.vmdk
-rw-------    1 root     root        8.5K Apr  4 14:31 dc.nvram
-rw-------    1 root     root         492 Mar 29 18:05 dc.vmdk
-rw-------    1 root     root           0 Nov 24  2013 dc.vmsd
-rw-------    1 root     root        4.2K Mar 31 17:48 dc.vmx
-rw-------    1 root     root           0 Mar 29 18:03 dc.vmx.lck
-rw-------    1 root     root        3.2K Jul 17  2015 dc.vmxf
-rw-------    1 root     root        4.2K Mar 31 17:48 dc.vmx~
-rw-------    1 root     root      166.0M Mar 29 18:03 vmx-dc-112910303-1.vswp
```

В виртуалке ничего конкретного не замечено, то есть ничего не растет. Но место уходит.
Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Буду рад любым наводкам.Спасибо.

Comment: А что за лог файл, который вы удалили и главное, вы процесс который этот лог писал перезапустили ? потому как в linux можно удалить открытый файл, но при это удаляется только запись каталога, инода продолжает использоваться и расти до завершения всех процессов открывших этот файл

Comment: я удалил: vmware.log в директории виртуальной машине. Процесс не перезагружал. Как он может расти если некуда ему писать?

Comment: Запись идет в инод. А имя файла в каталоге - это лишь указатель на инод по которому файл можно открыть. найдите pid процесса vmvare, зайдите в /proc/pid-процесса/fd/ и дайте там ls -l или по другому посмотрите открытые фалйловые дескрипторы, думаю вы там цвидите свой лог и даже командой tail сможете убедится, что файл все еще пишется

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Через lsof у меня получилось увидеть, что запущены процессы по записи лог файлов. Но так как на данном хосте крутит 3 вм, скорее всего я и увидел те самые процессы, которые пишут в остальные 2 ВМ.
Что я увидел в /proc, парочка директорий: bus, driver,mpt, net ,scsi.